# links to code samples for ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects

Newbie in ArcObjects.
Would like to expedite the learning process by looking at existing code samples.

Please paste links which would provide code samples for common tasks.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of snippets in the ArcObjects concept and samples area in resources:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html

See also the IDE snippets and samples in the API documentation:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this could be better answered by just saying online code repositories such as Codeplex and Google code and search by `ArcGIS`:

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=ArcGIS&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|&ac=8

http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=ArcGIS&projectsearch=Search+projects

<strike>I don't use [Easy ArcGIS Library](http://eagl.codeplex.com), but the code is on Codeplex and you can view can browse the code online if you just want snippets:</strike>

http://eagl.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41834#1172442

> Easy ArcGIS Library is a set of C#
>   .net classes that wrap the common
>   functionality of ArcObjects, that help
>   ArcGIS developers do a lot of common
>   functions in less time and direct way.
>
> ArcGIS is a complex system, that based
>   internally on ArcObjects, To program
>   with ArcObjects you have to work with
>   thousands of classes and interfaces,
>   and sometimes it is really
>   time-consuming task to do some simple
>   things.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one.

http://edn.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=codeExch.querySamples92&activeTab=samples&resultsFromCount=0&passedLanguage=All&passedCategory=All&products=All&languages=All&categories=&resultsPerPage=20&selectedOrder=Name

Answer (score 0):

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Draw_Polyline_Snippet/0049000000nr000000/